# Is it possible to have a custom domain on Heroku but handle the email accounts on another service?

Tags: heroku, dns

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question. I have an app hosted on Heroku with a custom domain and setting outgoing email up seems like a bad time.

I also have a web hosting account with Host Gator. I was curious if it's possible to still have the custom domain on Heroku while handling the sites email accounts elsewhere?

Thanks,

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Heroku doesn't actually handle the DNS itself. You just point the domain's A and/or CNAME records to Heroku's servers using your current DNS handler; the MX (mail) records are set independently of the A and CNAME records (also using your current DNS handler).

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem although you will need access to full DNS Records rather than just the Nameservers

Host Gator or your Domain Name Provider should be able to provide these.

To use Host Gator as the Email provider(if your nameservers are already pointing to Host Gator) you just need to set the DNS CNAME Record to point to your heroku URL see http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-change-dns-zones-mx-cname-and-a-records

Via your Domain Name Provider you will need to Point the CNAME record to Heroku but also set the MX record to point to your Email provider